# Connect android to local Lan via Phone (Over wifi OR via USB connection)

Tags: android, networking, video-streaming, lan, rtsp

I am playing about with RTSP in Android, getting it to stream using Media Player. Now I am wanting to test them locally, but finding it incredibly difficult.

What I have done is run a local Wowza server and published the RTSP url and I am then entering that URL into the android api demos MediaPlayerDemo.java. However, because it will not work on the emulator I have to debug this on my phone (HTC Hero 1.5) BUT I can not get my Hero to see my network in anyway.

Of course I can not use the 10.0.2.2 because that is for the emulator. I have also used the IP address of my computer and my other computer on the network but that doesn't either.

How do I get my Hero to see my network so I can test the RTSP streaming ?
I've tried connecting via USB and also connecting to my wifi router, but neither work.

Regards
Anthoni

Comment: Is your phone on the same wifi segment as the Wowza server?

Comment: try posting this question on superuser Q&A website (also by Stack Exchange). Your question is not related to software development... you wanna setup your network and then you can test your app.

Comment: Are you sure there's no firewall on your computer preventing the connection?